# Which names does GitHub recognize as README's?

Tags: github, readme

I know there are several names that get recognized by GitHub as README's, *e.g.* `README`, `README.md`.
What is an exhaustive list of such names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a searching [rule](https://github.com/ngryman/readme-filename/blob/master/index.js#L6)

```
const PATTERN = /^readme\.(?:markdown|mdown|mkdn|md|textile|rdoc|org|creole|mediawiki|wiki|rst|asciidoc|adoc|asc|pod|txt)/i
```

Comment: I don't speak fluent regex, would you be able to translate?

Comment: Is it like "in main directory, find PREFIX + 'readme' + SUFFIX contained in one of 'markdown', 'mdown', mkdn', ...etc" ?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct, plus that ignoring the cases `/i`

Comment: Thanks! Whay is that repo where you found this rule?

Comment: I have the link attached. Specifically, it is https://github.com/ngryman/readme-filename/blob/master/index.js#L6

Comment: No no, I got the link but I meant, is that the function used by GitHub to find whether a file is a readme or is it some guy's repo where he made a rule to find readme's?

Comment: I guess it is not an official repo, but it still can shed some lights how Github searching README files. If you really want to know how exactly Github searching README files, you can have a look on [readme](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-readmes#about-readmes), then further to [18F](https://github.com/18F/open-source-guide/blob/18f-pages/pages/making-readmes-readable.md), then to [uswds](https://github.com/uswds/uswds)..

Comment: @JorisLimonier they all will be finally pointing to https://designsystem.digital.gov/, a standard US government rules..